# My Fullscreen app is keeping the screen awake. How can I change this?

Tags: android, android-view, android-fullscreen

I'm creating my first fullscreen app and it looks great, but it's keeping the screen awake and I would like it not to. I don't understand why it's staying awake in the first place, so what should I do? Should I clear `View.KEEP_SCREEN_ON` after setting my flags? I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I could not find an answer. Thanks!

Here are the flags I set on an activity:

```
mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // call before setContentView to avoid system bars briefly showing
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        System.out.println("checking os version");
        if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            System.out.println("KitKat or newer");
            mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            );
        } else{
            System.out.println("Older than KitKat");
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure you're not setting `keepScreenOn` anywhere? If not, try doing `setKeepScreenOn(false);` after you set the flags.

Comment: Why do you use fullscreen and immersive mode and want to turn the screen off? It's a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: I discovered that the activity actually *wasn't* keeping the screen on. I just had my timeout set to 10 minutes. Sigh, bug tracking... as for why I want the screen off, my game is very simple and will be used by kids, who may leave it running anywhere and kill a battery.